# Aggregate raster data based on geopandas DataFrame geometries

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask, geopandas

**Situation**
I have two datasets:

1. Raster data loaded using `rioxarray`, an `xarray.DataArray`
2. An `geopandas.DataFrame` with `geometries` indicating areas in the 1. dataset

The geo data in both datasets are in the same CRS (EPSG:4326).

**Problem**
For each entry in 2. I want to aggregate all values from 1. which overlap with the specific `geometry`. Kind of like an `.group-by()` using the geometries + `.sum()`.

**Current WIP approach**
The package [`xagg`](https://github.com/ks905383/xagg) does that already, is unfortunately slow on a subset of my dataset and scales worse when I try to use it on my full dataset.

**Question**
Is there an simple and efficient way to do this in Python?
(The solution wouldn't need to replicate the results from `xagg` accurately.)

Comment: This is challenging to optimize, especially if your polygons cross raster boundaries. I've had success speeding up this process with large amounts of data (TBs) using dask and spreading it across a cluster. You could still see decent gains with dask or vanilla multiprocessing on a single machine.

Comment: If you can still capture the detail you need, simplifying your polygons and using coarser rasters can give huge speed increases. This is much easier than many other optimization solutions for this particular problem.

Comment: Can you share your code or hints on how you implemented a `dask` support solution to this? I think that might already help, as `xagg` with `rioxarray` only runs on a single core. (Maybe using `xarray` directly with `dask` and without `rioxarray` in between might already solve that, i'll give that a shot in the meantime).

Comment: You may want to ask on pangeo's discourse. You should be able to split your raster data into blocks, and for each block, find which polygons have any intersection, and only compute those. I don't know of a tool for this.

Comment: there are a number of scaling solutions: https://dask-geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html https://github.com/holoviz/spatialpandas

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would also help us try out some ideas with Dask :)

Comment: `xagg` v0.3.0 has a number of performance improvements (though no built-in support for multi-threading (yet)). It should be up on conda-forge soon - maybe it'll be fast enough then? If I remember, I'll bump this thread when it's up. In the meantime it's possible to grab it straight from the source [repo](https://github.com/ks905383/xagg) as well.

Comment: (but also if anyone finds out ways to optimize `xagg` using `dask` and wants to help us out with a PR we certainly wouldn't mind ;) )

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look together with a colleague of mine. (We noticed we have some code already that does the same job but hidden in one of our packages ... We "only" need to extract it, but it isn't a priority yet). I'll also post here if we get to it.

Comment: bumping that v0.3.0.1 is now (finally) up on conda-forge

Answer (score 0):

WRT your comment here is some pseudo code I've used to do what you're after. The function being executed outputs files in this case. If it's not obvious this, strategy isn't going to help if you just have 1 big raster and 1 big poly file. This method assumes tiled data and uses an indexing system to match the right rasters with the overlaying polys. The full example is kind of beyond the scope of a single answer. But if you ask specifics if you have issues I can try to assist. In addition to dask's good documentation, there are lots of other posts on here with dask delayed examples.

```
results_list = []

for f in raster_file_list: 

    temp_list = dask.delayed(your_custom_function)(f, your_custom_function_arg_1, your_custom_function_arg_2)
    results.append(temp_list)
    
results = dask.compute(*results_list, scheduler='processes')
```